# Аналог таймера из Handle

Tags: android, java

Можно ли с помощью класса Handler сделать аналог таймера (периодический запуск задачи по интервалу времени). Мой код:

```
class MyTask implements Runnable 
{
    public void run() 
    {
    // здесь меняем UI потока, создавшего Handler
    }
}

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new MyTask());
```

Необходимо, чтобы задача запускалась интервально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        //Что то делаем
        handler.postDelayed(runnable , 1000);
    }
};
```